# Paypal payment automatically for monthly subscription

Tags: asp.net, paypal

We are using Paypal payflow dll for payment process in our application. We are not storing the buyer card information in our local database for the first time of subscription with our product. We are storing the sale or Authorization transaction id in our database on first time of purchase, based on that we are creating Recurring payment profile on paypal with Billing cycle to renew their subscription automatically.

Based on the recurring payment status, we will do some operation from our application with automated service. The automated service will start @ 12AM, at that tiem we will do inquiry transaction for the recurring payment. If the payment success we will continue otherwise will send transaction failed mail to buyer.

Example, if the buyer purchase the product on August 1, 2015. The subscription will end on August 31, 2015. For the next time subscription we are passing the next payment date is August 31, 2015 to paypal. So the payment will happen on before August 31, 2015 6.00 AM. But the user wants to cancel on August 31 after noon (2.00 PM).

So the amount was taken 18 hours before. In that case we need to refund the amount.

To avaiod this situation, we can plan to get amount from buyer at that time of automated service running (12.00 AM). How can we achive this in paypal without storing buyer card information in local database.

Is there anyway with Recurring payment? Are we able to create profile information on paypal without amount value.

Could please provide suggetion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need to create a BillingAgreement when the user inserts his login data, then store the Billing Agreement ID and use that for the subsequent payments.

See here for an example from the PayPal website: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

Comment: Thanks for the Response. But We are using "Payflow_dotNET" dll to communicate with Paypal. We are not using API reference. We are not sure the billing agreement is possible with Classic "Payflow_dotNET" dll. Please provide your suggestion. Thanks